# ToolbarItem Icon does not appear in Android

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am creating an Android application in Xamarin Forms. I am trying to add a `ToolbarItem` icon using some of the examples from [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19225/icon-image-on-toolbar-item-in-xamarin-forms) forum using XAML like so:

```
<ToolbarItem Name="Add" Activated="OnAddClick"
           Priority="1" Order="Primary" Icon="Create.png" />
```

My `Create.png` icon file is located in `/Resources/drawable/` located in the Android project. I have done the same thing in Android Studio using a menu layout file and my icons are visible. I am, however, struggling to accomplish the same result in Xamarin Forms. Is this a problem with Xamarin Forms or am I doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try renaming your image to all lowercase and no special characters and try again. Android has restrictions on the filenames that are allowed for resources. In order to work on all platforms it must be valid for all platforms.

Comment: Yep, now it's working. I'm kinda wondering whether the folks on the forum I mentioned are aware of this because some of their examples had upper-case letters in their file names. Thanks Gerald!

Comment: Let me turn it into an answer for you :)

Comment: After using Android Studio for more than two years, I still make those silly mistakes. The good thing about Android Studio is it ***underlines*** the file which contains illegal characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for this to work truly cross-platform, make sure the filename is compliant with all of the requirements for each platform. Specifically Android is known to be picky. Just only lowercase filenames without any special characters. You can only use lower-case letters, numbers, underscores and periods.

Example valid filename is `create.png` or `icon_create.png`.

Non-valid examples are: `Create.png`, `icon create.png`, `create-icon.png`, etc.

Read more on the [Xamarin documentation page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/).

As pointed out in the comments, Xamarin Studio does an excellent job of pointing out the illegal filenames.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm pretty sure that underscores (`_`) are allowed in file names though I could be wrong.

Comment: It says underscores are allowed in the answer ;) Also please accept it as an answer if you see fit!

Comment: Accepted! Thanks again. Very helpful! ;)